# SonarQube warning on MSBuild version

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube

I am using `Sonar 5.3` server, and in `Jenkins` I am at `SonarQube Runner 2.2.1`. I recently upgraded sonar server from **4.5.2** to **5.3** but did not touch anything in `Jenkins`.

Now when I am Invoking SonarQube standalone analysis, then I am getting the things done, but I am getting warning

> WARN  - *                Use MSBuild 14 to get the best analysis
>   results                 *
>       WARN  - * The use of MSBuild 12 or the sonar-runner to analyze C# projects is DEPRECATED *

I just wanted to know what I should upgrade here? I installed `MSBuild 14.0` on the machine where `Sonar Analysis` is running. Do I need to upgrade `SonarRunner` plugin in `Jenkins` to ***latest 2.3***???

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild

On this site you can read that the support of MSBuild 12.0 is deprecated.
MSBuild.Runner with MSBuild 14.0 use SonarLint do analyse the source code.

Comment: Page has moved: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild